# Scanner.nextLine() is returning nothing when I try to use it twice

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am making an 8 ball program for my class final and I keep running into errors with the nextLine() function I am using. At first, without the input for the user, it had been printing the answer before any question was answered, and I had thought I'd figured it out, but then it returned nothing when I put them in the same for() loop. What am I doing wrong here? Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("8ball.txt"));
    Scanner reader2 = new Scanner(new File("medievalball.txt"));
    System.out.println("Welcome to 8 ball! You can choose a theme: Medieval or Normal, or type 'quit' to quit at any time.");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inInput = input.nextLine();
    String[] normal = new String[12];
    String[] medieval = new String[10];
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(10)+1;
    Random random2 = new Random();
    int randomNum2 = random2.nextInt(12)+1;
    while (true)
    {
    if (inInput.equals("Normal"))
    {
      System.out.println("You've selected Normal. Preparing... ");



      System.out.println("Ask me something, I can answer.");
      Scanner normalInput = new Scanner(System.in);

      for (int i=0; i < normal.length;i++)
      {
        normal[i] = normalInput.nextLine();
      }
    for (int i=0; i < normal.length;)
    {
      normal[i] = reader.nextLine();
     System.out.println(normal[randomNum]);
     break;
    }

    }

    else if (inInput.equals("Medieval"))
    {
      System.out.println ("You hath selected Medieval. Preparing...");
      System.out.println("I have unbearable knowledge of the world, ask me thine question.");
      Scanner medievalInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      for (int i=0; i < medieval.length;i++)
      {
        medieval[i] = medievalInput.nextLine();
      }
      for (int i=0; i < medieval.length;i++)
      {
        System.out.println(medieval[randomNum2]);
        break;
      }
    }
    else if (inInput.equals ("quit"))
    {
      System.out.println ("See you next time!");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Sorry, that's not a choice.");
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish in the loop? You seem to fill the array with the answer with the question?

Comment: I'm trying to get the 8 ball to read the user input and respond with a random line in a text file I gave it by value. I don't understand how I fill the array with the answer with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a good understanding of basics before you try to work on this problem. I've highlighted some of the problems from your program:

1. If the value of `normal.length >= 1`, the following statement will create an infinite loop. You need to put expression to change the value `i` (e.g. `i++`) in the last section of the loop statement.

   ```
   for (int i=0; i < normal.length;)
   ```
2. You do not need multiple instances of `Random` to generate more than one random numbers. Given below is an example of how to generate multiple random numbers using the same instance of `Random`.

   ```
   Random random = new Random();
   int randomNum = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
   int randomNum2 = random.nextInt(12) + 1;
   ```
3. Whenever you read something from a file using a scanner, you should always use `Scanner::hasNextLine` to avoid `NoSuchElementException` e.g. the following code block

   ```
   for (int i=0; i < normal.length; i++) {
       normal[i] = reader.nextLine();
       //...
   }
   ```

   should be written as

   ```
   for (int i=0; i < normal.length && reader.hasNextLine(); i++) {
       normal[i] = reader.nextLine();
       //...
   }
   ```
4. The `break` without a condition is meaningless in a loop e.g. the `break` statement in the following block will cause the loop to terminate after the first iteration refuting the purpose of using the loop.

   ```
   for (int i=0; i < medieval.length;i++) {
       System.out.println(medieval[randomNum2]);
       break;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this, this helped me a lot! I just have one thing I stumbled on, when I didn’t use break, the same line would be read 12 times for normal and 10 times for medieval. I can’t exactly figure out how to fix this.

Comment: You are most welcome. The reason for multiple prints may be due to some other enclosing loop which I or anyone else can be able to comment on only after seeing the content of the files. I suggest you post a new question with all the changes you have done after these comments. Do not edit this question; otherwise, this answer will become irrelevant. When you post the new question, make sure to use the relevant title and include the content of the files, `8ball.txt` and `medievalball.txt` as well in the question.